# Is there a list of sound absorption coefficients for common types of paper/cardboard?

Tags: acoustics

I am looking for a list of Sound Absorption Coefficients for common types of paper/cardboard.

I googled and got this [list](http://www.bobgolds.com/AbsorptionCoefficients.htm), which only has 2 items labeled "Paper Out".

it does not seem to be Absorption Coefficients for paper.

Is there a list of Sound Absorption Coefficients for common types of paper/cardboard?

Comment: Those numbers are irrelevant for what you want. They are for a thick layer of fiberglass wool (3.5 or 6.25 inches thick), covered with a paper sheet which acts as a moisture barrier. Note that for most frequencies, the paper *reduces* the sound absorption compared with unfaced rockwool data in the same table. See https://www.homedepot.com/b/Building-Materials-Insulation-Fiberglass-Insulation/Owens-Corning/N-5yc1vZbay7Z3q5 for what this stuff looks like. It is commonly used for thermal insulation not sound insulation.

Comment: I would expect the sound absorption coefficient of paper itself to be negligible, unless you construct a sound-absorbing 3-dimensional structure using it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization

Comment: @alephzero Thanks for your comments. Does "a sound-absorbing 3-dimensional structure" mean a lab where all 6 of walls full of some type of paper?